# How get file path by handle in windbg?

Tags: windows, windbg, handle

How I can obtain file path from handle with windbg/kd in kernel mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `!handle <handle_num> 7 <proc_id>` to display detailed information for that handle where `<handle_num>` is the handle value and `<proc_id>` is the process id value (both hex based) see this [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) link for further information.

You can gleam your process id from a user mode session, this is the easiest method, just attach in user mode and enter the pipe command `|` and it will output like so:

> .  0  id: 1680    attach  name: D:\test\MyApp.exe

so `1680` would be the proc id, then list the handles using `!handle` and then in kernel mode enter:

```
!handle <handle_num> 7 1680
```

will display what you want, there is a useful blog entry on this [here](http://www.bytetalk.net/2009/03/windbg-tips-and-tricks.html).

Comment: Thats all I had `code`kd> !handle f 000000c8 

PROCESS 8c0a7cf8  SessionId: 1  Cid: 0150    Peb: 7ffdf000  ParentCid: 0148
    DirBase: 3f4c70a0  ObjectTable: 9e40bea8  HandleCount: 176.
    Image: csrss.exe

000f: Object: 8b79a6b0  GrantedAccess: 00000804 `code`
But I want file name on disk, which handle describe.

Comment: You need the handle number and your process id, so for instance `!handle <handle_num> 7 <proc_id>` this will dump the info for that handle