# WinDbg | Application memory full dump - Show file path of file handle

Tags: debugging, windbg

I created a memory dump of an application with `procdump -ma abc.exe`.
The application access various files.

I run `!handle 0 f FILE` and get over 100 file handles.
When I get a specific handle address, I run the following command `!handle 000000000000161c f` which results in:

```c
0:000> !handle 000000000000161c f
Handle 000000000000161c
  Type          File
  Attributes    0
  GrantedAccess 0x12019f:
         ReadControl,Synch
         Read/List,Write/Add,Append/SubDir/CreatePipe,ReadEA,WriteEA,ReadAttr,WriteAttr
  HandleCount   2
  PointerCount  65479
  No object specific information available
```

Is there a chance to retrieve the actual file path? Something like that: [How get file path by handle in windbg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14857736/how-get-file-path-by-handle-in-windbg) seems to work only in kernel mode debugging.

Comment: Sadly no, the relationship between the handle numerical value and the object name (if any) is kept at the kernel level. This doesn't even work with a live process in user-mode debugging. You'd really need a kernel debugger (live or full kernel dump) to retrieve the object name. In user-mode, one - not so practical - possibility would be to get all handles, interrogate their types, and if they are a named object, interrogate the kernel to get that name, then perform the dump at roughly the same time...

Comment: @Neitsa: there's an extension for that. Live debugging only, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For post-mortem debugging (crash dump analysis), there's no way, except if you have a kernel dump (I can't tell you how to do that then). Windows will close handles of a process that terminated.

### !handle combined with !handleex

There is [handleex on Github](https://github.com/tahadraidia/windbg-arsenal/tree/main/handleex).

Combine `!handle` and `!handleex` to get nice information.

```
.foreach /pS 1 /ps 1 (file {!handle 0 4 FILE}) { .echo Handle file; !handleex file; .echo }
```

Example output

```
0:007> .foreach /pS 1 /ps 1 (file {!handle 0 4 FILE}) { .echo Handle file; !handleex file; .echo }
Handle 4c
Object Type: File
Handle Name: \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Users\T

Handle 8c
Object Type: File
Handle Name: \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.19041.1110_none_60b5254171f9507e

Handle b4
Object Type: File
Handle Name: \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\System32\en-US\notepad.exe.mui

...
```

### !handle combined with SysInternals Handle

You can combine the `!handle` WinDbg command and the [SysInternals Handle tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle).

Example notepad debugging session:

```
:018> !handle 0 1 FILE
Handle 4c
  Type          File
Handle 8c
  Type          File
Handle b8
  Type          File
Handle 134
  Type          File
...
```

Combined with the information from the console:

```
C:\...>handle -p notepad.exe | findstr 8C:
   8C: File          C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.19041.1110_none_60b5254171f9507e

C:\...>handle -p notepad.exe | findstr B8:
   B8: File          C:\Windows\System32\en-US\notepad.exe.mui
```

Automating it doesn't really work well:

```
0:007> .printf "%d\n",$tpid
2168
0:007> .foreach /pS 1 /ps 1 (file {!handle 0 4 FILE}) { .shell C:\handle.exe -p 2168 | findstr file: }
```

The process seems to be too slow and require too much user input.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I didn't know about this extension!

Comment: thanks for the answer. I'll play around with the handleex extension! :-)